Is there a way to create a BTC wallet with an unusually nice Bech-32 address?
For example, let's say I want a wallet address that contains only numerical digits, or that contains only letters from the first half of the alphabet. How can I ensure I get such an address?

The concept you are referring to is called "vanity address". Check out the topics labeled [tag:vanity-address].
